# SELECT $x(php variable) FROM

Tags: php, mysql

I`m trying to echo a single string from mysql database. There are columns in database (en, es, de, it...) representing different languages and I want to select value from one row and from column with current language ($language="en", or $language="es"...). I have tried:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT "' .$language. '" FROM page WHERE 
title="findInstructor" LIMIT 1');
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
print_r($row[0]);
?>
```

The problem is, I am getting on screen value of `$language` variable, not a value from database. If I try it f.e. for english language, everything if fine:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT en FROM page WHERE 
title="findInstructor" LIMIT 1');
```

Or if I could do something like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM page WHERE 
title="findInstructor" LIMIT 1');
....
print_r($row[$language]);
```

Thanks for an answer!

Comment: What does this even mean: `getting on screen value of $language variable`?

Comment: try without any quotation

Comment: Try that way `'SELECT ' .$language. ' FROM page WHERE 
title="findInstructor" LIMIT 1'`

Comment: Thanks guys a lot, it works!!!!

Comment: @Enstage it was printing value of $language (en, es... etc), but the problem is solved. Thank you!

Comment: You can accept any answer, but please tell me why accept later answer and not my answer? @MichalKotus

Comment: @MohammadHamedani, Because he might not be aware of post timing or might not get your query in full PHP code. If I were there, I choose your answer!! I faced this situation many times.

Comment: @MohammadHamedani You can't force anyone to this level...!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because wrap `$language` with double quotes and `SELECT` treat it as a string and not column name. Try this:

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT ' .$language. ' FROM page WHERE 
        title="findInstructor" LIMIT 1');
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    print_r($row[0]);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown in below code if you put variable name in double quote,it's consider it as a static value.

```
'SELECT "' .$language. '" FROM page WHERE 
title="findInstructor" LIMIT 1'
```

So instead of this you have to try below code

```
'SELECT ' .$language. ' FROM page WHERE 
title="findInstructor" LIMIT 1'
```

Hope this will help you.